# Remove records from db using NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

So I want to remove a whole series of objects from my DB.

They are temporarily stored in an NSMutableArray.

This is my current code where I loop through them.

```
+(BOOL) removeLogs:(Logs *)logs {
Database *db = [DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager].db;

sqlite3_exec(db.dataBase, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);
const char *sqlRemoveLogs = "DELETE FROM logs WHERE LogID = ?";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db.dataBase, sqlRemoveLogs, -1, &removeLogStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db.dataBase));
    return NO;
}

for(int i = 0; i < logs.getLogs.count; i++) {
    sqlite3_bind_int(removeLogStatement, 1, [logs getLogAtIndex:i].logId);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(removeLogStatement)) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to remove logs: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db.dataBase));
        return NO;
    }

    sqlite3_clear_bindings(removeLogStatement);
    sqlite3_reset(removeLogStatement);
}

sqlite3_finalize(removeLogStatement);

NSLog(@"Logs removed");
return YES;
}
```

I want to get this in the form where I do now have to use a for loop to iterate through them.
using following statement for sqlite:

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE LogID IN ?
```

How do I fill this '?' with the NSMutableArray?
Is it even possible to do this?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:
the "Logs" object is an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an `NSArray` of `logIds` you want to delete and save it in `logIdsToDeleteArray`.

Then follow these steps;

Step 1:

```
NSString * logIdsToDelete = [[logIdsToDeleteArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Result: Array elements combine and become a string of comma separated elements.

Step 2:

```
NSString *logIdsToDelete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}", logIdsToDelete];
```

Result: {element1, element2, element 3 ..} as an `NSString`

Step 3:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM logs WHERE LogID IN %@", logIdsToDelete];
```

Result: required sql statement as `NSString`

Step 4:

```
const char *sql = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Result: sqlite3 compatible `const char`

You will get the sql statement you want to execute and then proceed as you have done in your code snippet.